# ZMQDevice in PHP

Tags: php, zeromq

I'm trying to use `$listener` with IPC socket with ZMQDevice, but I receive nothing, if I switch to TCP, it works.

```
    ZMQDevice::__construct ( ZMQSocket $frontend, ZMQSocket $backend, ZMQSocket $listener)
```

pub.php

```
    $context = new ZMQContext();

    $frontend = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_XXX);
    $frontend->bind("tcp://...");

    $backend = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_XXX);
    $backend->bind("ipc://backend.ipc");

    $listener = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUB);
    $listener->bind("ipc://witness.ipc");

    $device = new ZMQDevice($frontend, $backend, $listener);
    $device->run()
```

sub.php

```
    $context = new ZMQContext();

    $receiver = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_SUB);
    $receiver->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_SUBSCRIBE, '');
    $receiver->connect("ipc://witness.ipc");
```

Environment:

```
    libzmq1:amd64   2.2.0+dfsg-5
    zmq for PHP was installed with pecl
```

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Help you with what? Trying? Please add more detail to your post, otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: How did you acquire the context? Is this the same process in question? Which version of ZMQ do you have and how did you install the extension (PECL or github)?

Comment: Is there any big different between PECL and compilation with source from github?

Comment: There is. The extension at github contains several major differences that allows for proper use of IPC / INPROC transports, especially when using pthreads or forks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, I found out why, I forgot that the device was executed in another directory.